# Do the Categories of Rings With a Particular Characteristic Have Terminal Objects?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For a given characteristic n, is there a unital ring T of characteristic n such that for any other unital ring R of characteristic n, there is a unique ring homomorphism from R to T? It's easy to see that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is initial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible if $n\neq 1$: suppose there is such a ring, and call it $A$. It's a $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-algebra in a natural way.

Then there is a unique $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$-algebra morphism $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[x]\to A$. But such morphisms are in natural bijection with the elements of $A$, so $A$ only has one element, and then $O_A = 1_A$ so the characteristic of $A$ is $1$.

Comment: This makes me realize that what I showed is that "in a concrete category with free objects, a terminal object must have one element".